# How to auto launch an EC2 instance to another availability zone in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm newbie to AWS. I have an EC2 Windows instance where my server is running in one availability zone of a region.

My need is reliability of the instance if region/availability zone goes down. I know that snapshots or AMIs are a way of taking backup. Replication of instance to multiple availability zones also possible.

My Question?

1) what is the probability of an instance or region goes down?

2) Is there any way to auto launch of a running instance to another availability zone or to another region if the availability zone or region of my instance goes down?

3) Better way for reliability of instance?

All possible suggestions are welcome. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always possible for an instance or an availability zone to become "unavailable". The mantra for the cloud is "everything will fail, plan for it".

Don't wait for your instance to become unavailable. Depending on the reason for the unavailability, you may not be able to launch a replacement instance in the same region.

At the very least, make sure you have an AMI image of your EC2 instance ready in case your EC2 instance fails or becomes unavailable. This allows you to launch a fresh replacement instance. However, any data that was saved to the original EC2 instance after the AMI image was created would not be present on the fresh instance.

For reliability, you should run multiple EC2 instances in multiple availability zones behind a load balancer (ELB or similar).

For extra reliability, you could run your application in multiple regions and use Route53 health checks with failovers to move traffic away from the problem region.